# Why is there a blank line at the top of my html page?

Tags: html

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div>
kjkj
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Lve demo:
http://tinkerbin.com/O2MwkUTj

Why is there a blank line at the top of my web page?

I noticed that removing the div, or removing the doctype fixes the problem...

Comment: It seems to be related to tinkerbin.com.  Running this example locally does not produce the blank line. When viewing the source code via firebug on tinkerbin, the meta tag is being placed within the body which is strange.  This also leads me to believe they have an issue on their end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because Tinkerbin is getting confused.

If you put your HTML into a file it works fine. In Tinkerbin, the following happens in the preview:

```
<body>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <div>
    kjkj
    </div>
</body>
```

I presume it is removing some tags such as `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` when outputting your page in order to display inside a page created for the preview.